# Unit testing WCF Data Service (OData) Client library with fakes using shims

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a class library which consumes a WCF data service (OData), is it possible to create unit tests for the library api by isolating the WCF Data service using shims(not stubs), i was searching for a sample but couldn't find any, any pointers ?

Comment: What have you tried? See [Creating Testable WCF Data Services | Dmitry Frenkel](http://dimafr.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/creating-testable-wcf-data-services/), [WCF Data Services performance - eidias](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2011/11/28/wcf-data-services-performance), [Testablility and WCF Data Services - TechHui](http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/testablility-and-wcf-data-services) and tons of other web search hits.